# Failed to resolve type MvvmCross.Platform.UI.IMvxNativeColor

Tags: mvvmcross

I am trying to use the `MvvmCross.Plugin.Color` library so that I can use a converter for colors. Here is my converter:

```
public class MyColorValueConverter : MvxColorValueConverter<bool>
{
    protected override MvxColor Convert(bool value, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value ? new MvxColor(19, 119, 51) : new MvxColor(171, 8, 16);
    }
}
```

And in the .xml:

```
<MyView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    local:MvxBind="BackgroundColor MyColor(MyBool)" />
```

But when I raise the property change of MyBool, I get an exception with this message:

> MvvmCross.Platform.Exceptions.MvxIoCResolveException: Failed to
>   resolve type MvvmCross.Platform.UI.IMvxNativeColor at
>   MvvmCross.Platform.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.Resolve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the plugin gets registered against the IoC container and is install in the platform projects as well as your core project.

This can would normally be done via the plugin bootstrap class. Which is normally included when you install the `MvvmCross.Plugin.Color` in your platform project. However, if you are using Nuget via `project.json` the additional bootstrap class will no automatically get included.

Create a folder `Bootstrap` of the root of your android project and a `ColorPluginBootstrap.cs`

```
using MvvmCross.Platform.Plugins;

namespace {{Your name space}}.Bootstrap
{
    public class ColorPluginBootstrap
        : MvxPluginBootstrapAction<MvvmCross.Plugins.Color.PluginLoader>
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also add this to your `MvxAndroidSetup` of your Android project instead:

```
protected override IEnumerable<Assembly> ValueConverterAssemblies
{
    get
    {
        var toReturn = base.ValueConverterAssemblies.ToList();
        toReturn.Add(typeof(MvxNativeColorValueConverter).Assembly);
        return toReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct, just a note, the `MvvmCross.Plugins.Color` contains additional converts (`MvxRGBValueConverter`, `MvxRGBAValueConverter` etc.) that would also need to be registered if required. Using the boostrap approach allow for the plugin to manage this all for you